# Generate all halting Smallfuck programs of length n

Tags: code-challenge, code-generation, halting-problem

Your task is to write a program that, given a number *n*, returns a list of all valid, halting [Smallfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Smallfuck) programs of length *n*, in any order.

Actually, we're using a variation of Smallfuck called [F2](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fm), which is just Smallfuck with a right-unbounded tape. For the purposes of this challenge, a program that moves left from the start of the tape is considered invalid, as is one with unbalanced brackets.

### Scoring

Since solving this for every *n* is impossible (as it would require you to solve the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)), your submission's score will be the lowest *n* for which it returns an incorrect answer.

Each submission must be, at most, 1000 bytes (though you are encouraged to provide an ungolfed version as well). In the event of a tie, the earlier answer wins.

### Test Cases

*n* = 1:

```
+ >
```

*n* = 2:

```
++ +> >+ >< >> []
```

*n* = 3:

```
+++ ++> +>+ +>< +>> >++ >+< >+> ><+ ><> >>+ >>< >>> >[] [+] [<] [>] []+ []>
```

*n* = 4:

```
++++ +++> ++>+ ++>< ++>> +>++ +>+< +>+> +><+ +><> +>>+ +>>< +>>> >+++ >++< >++> >+<+ >+<> >+>+ >+>< >+>> ><++ ><+> ><>+ ><>< ><>> >>++ >>+< >>+> >><+ >><< >><> >>>+ >>>< >>>> [][] ++[] +>[] ><[] >>[] [++] [+<] [+>] [<+] [<<] [<>] [>+] [><] [>>] []++ []+> []>+ []>< []>> +[+] +[>] >[+] >[<] >[>] >[]+ >[]< >[]> [+]+ [+]> [<]+ [<]> [>]+ [>]> [[]]
```

Please inform me if there are any more that I have forgotten to add.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60129/discussion-on-question-by-challenger5-generate-all-halting-smallfuck-programs-of).

Comment: For n=3 assuming 2-way unbounded tape, we get <[] as well.

Comment: @user75200 "For the purposes of this challenge, a program that moves left from the start of the tape is considered invalid."

Comment: This challenge is effectively just "write a Smallfuck implementation and find all programs that halt after at least G steps, where G is the largest constant you can fit under 1000 bytes."

Answer (score 6):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), Score: ???

This clocks in at 980 bytes, since I had so much to work with I decided to make it a little more readable.  Basically I'm generating all the possible programs for length n and iterating them n^x times for some x.  x is currently 3 but it can be modified arbitrarily to any size, limited only by the limitation of the JVM's precission.  This will work for arbitrarily large input values if x is increased, but I have it set to 3 for tio.

```java
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        int x = 3;
        l:for(int j=0;j<Math.pow(5, i);j++){
            try {
                String s="";
                for(int k=j;s.length()<i;k/=5)
                    s="+<>][".charAt(k%5)+s;
                Stack<Integer>y=new Stack<Integer>();
                Map<Integer,Integer>f=new HashMap<>(),b=new HashMap<>();
                for(int m=0; m<s.length();m++){
                    char c=s.charAt(m);
                    if(c=='[')y.push(m);
                    if(c==']'){int n=y.pop();f.put(n, m);b.put(m, n);}
                }
                if(y.size()>0)
                    continue;
                boolean[] t= new boolean[s.length()];
                int l=0,n=0;
                for(long m=0;l<s.length()&m<Math.pow(i,x);l++,m++){
                    switch(s.charAt(l)){
                    case'+':t[n]=!t[n];break;
                    case'>':n++;break;
                    case'<':n--; if(n < 0)continue l;break;
                    case'[':if(!t[n])l=f.get(l);break;
                    case']':l=b.get(l)-1;break;
                    }
                }
                if(l>=s.length()){
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            } catch(Exception e){continue;}
        }
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVNNj5swED2TX@FGarELoanaXGIcqYdK7WFPOUYcDOsEgxkj7Gw2jfLbU/OVj80BY715M/PeDBT8jc90LaB4LS8XWdW6sahwYLS3UkVf6aTep0pmKFPcGPTCJZwm3oAZy617vWn5iioXwWvbSNhtEsSbnSGO6EmwSCKGQBzQOuMAosHro7GiiiSQCMS7/QsWE@q4arnVDW4zCjanRfzCbR7V@oAXIZKEFkHQlfRsc0Tdxev7IcOmU9oBY4GSFdRESsDO5pjEkpbf2IJ0FM@xg3iVbKZRlvPml8Xl5wUJDB0q8qyMnSSxE83qyDrdD1iv1fNeeD1i4Rjbdvw/3ORt1FHD9CPyqLNyRlEV36TSanTpea08lDEz6qyGZE9uccaYv/HJMar3Jn@KJD45teWBOYKuXdmtI1oMIXLUtLtXIQJCz11ef7rkY2TkP4HJaj4MK9NgJexFXz/VWgkObsG2X@kI3AwkPbPtrtg8BGfw6lhpt6zWsrpz/KW6LVqGPwhVQRDeTcEcpM1yfJ2CItf5cCP8wF/aDSTsU3vStBG8pHfhlb@EIHjGY4fPZhQ5z4BiNCejUaSeyRt/6XhdB6LYNtqJVsYzL/GXiqVDePb9gfBh0GrFbiMYDQ0/ht7bqHYftlWAzbDZLvGMMt7O4vd7JmorNSBBTtcNtRT3nCfny@Xnfw)

Comment: My guess is that the first program that breaks this will be some sort of counting-in-binary program. I'm not sure exactly how long that would be, though.

Comment: I did the same thing in Python, but just had no way of proving anything.  It amused me how difficult the proof felt compared to the actual code.

Comment: `>>>>>>>>+[[<]+>>>>>>>>+[+<<<<<<<[+>]]<+]` is a program that SHOULD do binary counting (I don't know if that part works correctly), is 40 characters long (40*40=1600), and takes 4451 steps to run.  I don't think it's the minimum program that takes longer than `n*n` steps to run, just an example.

Comment: @nmjcman101 Thanks for the input, I've updated the code to do n\*n\*n but set a variable x to allow it to arbitrarily be increased.  I'm not sure what the score would be at x=3,4,5... and I don't know how I would begin calculating it, so I'm just going to leave it unknown

Comment: @PunPun1000 per the halting problem, there is no x such that this algorithm can determine if an arbitrary F2 program halts - indeed, we could then just convert any problem to F2 and solve the halting problem with your algorithm.

Comment: @Sanchises I know. That's why I said that you could increase x for arbitrary score, not that there was any x which for which there was infinite score

Comment: @PunPun1000 It's impossible to calculate the score as a function of x in general- it turns out that that is equivalent to solving the halting problem :p There is a maximum score that you can provably achieve by increasing x (though my inclination is that this maximum is itself not computable)

Answer (score 2):

## Braingolf, Score: 3

```
1-?"++ +> >+ >< >> []":"+ >"|&@
```

Start things off nice and easy, hardcodes the correct answer for 1 and 2, outputs `+ >` if n = 1, and `++ +> >+ >< >> []` otherwise

Comment: Also add `[]` for another length-2 testcase.